# How can I programmatically increase the height of the cells in my UITableView?

Tags: iphone, ipad, ios

I'm diving into iOS development and I just finished reading Apple doc "A closer look at table view cells", but I couldn't find the answer to my question.  If I have a UITableView in one of the views of my iOS app, how can I increase the height of the cells?  I assume this is something I would do in the `cellForRowAtIndexPath` delegate method, and it would probably involve adjusting the frame of the cell, but I don't understand how to do that without screwing up the position of the cells, which is currently determined by the iOS.  Anyhow, I'm clearly confused, can anyone explain how I can increase the height of the cells in my UITableView?

Thanks so much in advance for your help!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can do so either with the

```
- (CGFloat) tableView: (UITableView *) tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath: (NSIndexPath *) indexPath
```

`UITableViewDelegate` method or the `rowHeight` property of `UITableView`.

Comment: If this ends up working for you, don't forget to click the √ button next to my answer! :)